# Is there a good way to filter and remove individual rows using conditions?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I want to filter and remove rows using Dplyr piping. A column called TimeGap has values 1, 2, 3.  I want to remove the rows that are directly above the TimeGap value 2.

Example Dataframe called TimeDifference

```
   Site   Result   TimeGap
1. 1       120       1
2. 1       50        3
3. 1       100       3
4. 2       500       1
5. 2       888       3
6. 2       456       3
7. 3       123       1
8. 3       458       2
9. 3       654       3
10. 4       789       1
11. 4       785       2
12. 4       894       3
13. 4       123       3
14. 5       10        1
15. 5       5         3
16. 5       41        3
17. 6       23        1
18. 6       24        2
19. 6       55        3
20. 6       69        1
21. 6       5         2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `lead` function, which points to the next row.

If I understood your question correctly, you want to filter a row out if the next row has `TimeGap==2`. Here is the code:

```
db=read.table(header=T,text="
row Site   Result   TimeGap
1. 1       120       1
2. 1       50        3
3. 1       100       3
4. 2       500       1
5. 2       888       3
6. 2       456       3
7. 3       123       1#remove
8. 3       458       2
9. 3       654       3
10. 4       789       1#remove
11. 4       785       2
12. 4       894       3
13. 4       123       3
14. 5       10        1
15. 5       5         3
16. 5       41        3
17. 6       23        1#remove
18. 6       24        2
19. 6       55        3
20. 6       69        1#remove
21. 6       5         2")

db2=db %>% filter(lead(TimeGap)!=2)
setdiff(db$row, db2$row)
# [1]  7 10 17 20 21
```

This filtered out rows 7, 10, 17, 20, and 21 as expected.